# Sqlite3 database performance

Tags: sqlite, database-performance

I want create database. Simple I think. Just to storage number of phone, date, time and note.
Better (for database perfomance) use new table for every phone number and notes or one table and all information in it?

Comment: if only this much fields and no other table dependancy than it would be better to store in singe table else depends on details

Comment: No more fields. Only those.

Comment: It would be more easy to retrive relevant data from a single table compare to making multiple tables and retriving from that.

Answer (score 1):

The *right way* is to normalize your data (hence, use as much tables as needed).

If you split your data into several tables (assuming you use indexed) [write performance will be better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17110004/89771).

Regarding read performance, depends on the size of the data (namely notes), but I would argue that having more tables is also better - except if indexing is out of the question (no reason for that really) and if you would otherwise need to join tables to get data. Even then, I don't think it would be a big trade-off.

SQLite can write millions of rows/s and read another more, are you sure you want to ask this question?