# Scala Slick 2.0 and SQlite3 insert speed and PRAGMA

Tags: sqlite, slick, pragma

This questions is similar to these:

- [SQLite insert speed slows as number of records increases due to an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778716/sqlite-insert-speed-slows-as-number-of-records-increases-due-to-an-index)
- [Improve INSERT-per-second performance of SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite)

I have to index certain features from the Wikipedia XML dump. The parsing is fast. However, insert is slow.

Switching off indexing doubled the speed.

I batch insert like this:

```
    articles.grouped(5000)
           .foreach {
              batch: IterableView[(Article, List[Category], List[Link]), Iterable[_]] =>
                //Save each batch in one transaction
                database withTransaction {
                 implicit session =>
                   for(i <- batch) {
                     articles += i._1
                     categories ++= i._2
                     links ++= i._3
                   }

               }
            }
```

I read that `journal_mode = MEMORY` and `synchronous = off` increase the insert speed. How do I set these with slick? I am using c3p0 as a connection pool and added `PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY` to `preferredTestQuery`. I don't believe this is the right way to set these options.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19); you should use one transaction for all inserts.

Comment: This is what `withTransaction` does or should do. One transaction for all Wikipedia articles might be a little too much.

Comment: What do you mean with "too much"? Multiple transaction certainly are too slow …

Comment: Well, if I add all articles in one transaction I will have millions of inserts which add up to around 40GB. If I cannot switch of journaling this might cause problems. If there is an error I will loose everything instead of "just" 5000 articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are reading data once, locally. You could just not use transactions at all and use `withSession` instead. And if you still need a pragma you can set it via plain SQL. You probably want to reset the pragma after use to not leave a side-effect.

```
import scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery.interpolation

database withSession {
  implicit session =>
  sqlu"PRAGMA synchronous=OFF".execute
  articles.grouped(5000)
         .foreach {
            batch: IterableView[(Article, List[Category], List[Link]), Iterable[_]] =>
              //Save each batch in one transaction
               for(i <- batch) {
                 articles += i._1
                 categories ++= i._2
                 links ++= i._3
               }
           }
}
```

Also interesting to know is that not only database has a `withTransaction` method, but also session. So you can do `session.withTransaction` within a `withSession` block re-using the same connection.

Comment: `sqlu"PRAGMA ...".execute` worked. I used `sql"PRAGMA..."` which did not work. I look into using just one session.

Comment: I tested on a subset that includes ca. 5500 articles. switching off journaling and synchronous makes a difference. However, moving the `withSession` outside of the foreach does not make a big difference. I guess that is because there is no indexing or journaling.

Answer (score 2):

In Slick 3.2.0, the following lines seem to work:

```
import org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig
import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database
import slick.jdbc.SQLiteProfile.api._
...
val sqliConfig = new SQLiteConfig();
sqliConfig.setJournalMode(SQLiteConfig.JournalMode.MEMORY)
sqliConfig.setSynchronous(SQLiteConfig.SynchronousMode.OFF)
val emailsDB = Database.forURL(
  "jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/my/dbfile.sqlite",
  driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC",
  prop = sqliConfig.toProperties
)
```

where `org.sqlite` is from :

```
libraryDependencies += "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.16.1"
```